# I need to pass Json via Controller To View. HOW?

Tags: json, laravel

I have This Task i have been giving to do .All I need To do is Pass Json file (Meaning Reading it from storage) By the controller and then return it to the view and display it  .That's All.

```
My Controller Function

public function ReadFromStorage(){

        $path = Storage::get(storage_path('widget.json'));

        return   view('read', compact(path));
    }


My Route

Route::get('/read','ReadJsonController@ReadFromPublic');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
My Controller Function

public function ReadFromPublic(){

        $path = Storage::get('widget.json');

        return view('read', compact('path'));
    }


My Route

Route::get('/read','ReadJsonController@ReadFromPublic');
```

And if your'e using the public disk(used by default), don't forget to run `php artisan storage:link`
You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

Comment: And how do i print it in blade please

Comment: The regular way, `{{$path}}`. בהצלחה אחי.

Comment: File not found at path: widget.json (0)

Comment: Continue in english bro, see that the route is not the same as the function. i will update mt answer.

Comment: Please accept it as the answer and an upvote please!

Comment: @SagyCohen If this has answered you're question please can you mark it as accepted so that the question can be closed. Thanks :)

Comment: @RossWilson My guess is that he cant upvote because of low points. if you upvote his question, i believe he will be able becaue he will reach the point needed(10, no?)

Comment: @SagyCohen Please accept this answer by clicking the "v" next to the upvotes and downvotes buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // controller
   public function ReadFromPublic(){
      $path = public_path('clients.json');
      $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($path));
      $clients = $data->clients;

    return view('read', compact('clients'));
    }


  // view file
  @foreach($clients as $client)
   <div>
    {{$client->name}}
   </div>
  @endforeach
```

// sample json file

```html
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "id": "59761c23b30d971669fb42ff",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 36,
      "name": "Dunlap Hubbard",
      "gender": "male",
      "company": "CEDWARD",
      "email": "dunlaphubbard@cedward.com",
      "phone": "+1 (890) 543-2508",
      "address": "169 Rutledge Street, Konterra, Northern Mariana Islands, 8551"
    },
    {
      "id": "59761c233d8d0f92a6b0570d",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 24,
      "name": "Kirsten Sellers",
      "gender": "female",
      "company": "EMERGENT",
      "email": "kirstensellers@emergent.com",
      "phone": "+1 (831) 564-2190",
      "address": "886 Gallatin Place, Fannett, Arkansas, 4656"
    },
    {
      "id": "59761c23fcb6254b1a06dad5",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 30,
      "name": "Acosta Robbins",
      "gender": "male",
      "company": "ORGANICA",
      "email": "acostarobbins@organica.com",
      "phone": "+1 (882) 441-3367",
      "address": "697 Linden Boulevard, Sattley, Idaho, 1035"
    }
  ]
}
```